# How to use keyboards function with _getch(), as it is possible with getline()?

Tags: c++, getline, getch

My problem is that I want to do a special thing when my user is pushing tabulation in the terminal. My first code explains that :

```
char buffer[100];

while (true)
{
    std::cin.getline(buffer, 100); // do IMMEDIATELY something if 'tabulation' was used ?

}
```

So I asked myself how to check every chars ? I tried with **_getch();**

```
while (true)
{
    c = _getch();

    if (c == '\t')
        // do something special
    else
        std::cout << (char)c;
}
```

But now, I can't use any specials functions keys as arrows, del, suppr, etc... I can't ***move*** into what am I typing as I can with `getline()`

So is there any solutions to do a special interruption in a middle of a `getline()` ? 
Or is it possible to use `_getch()` in a different way ?
I also tried to do an other thread (one with `getline()` and the other with `_getch()` for checking every ) but I'm not so sure about what I can do with threads.

It could be possible to handle every special function (arrows keys, del, suppr, etc...) 'manually' but I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: No, there isn't in standard c++. That's OS and terminal specific.

Comment: why don't you use stdin or scanf?

Comment: Did you read the part of the documentation which explains the values `_getch` can return? Are you aware that you may need to call `_getch` twice to get a single key code?

Comment: @Gugg That won't help either.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I read, but even if I can detect those keycodes, what can I do with it ? For example, I can detect arrows keys codes, but all I have as solutions remaining is only to emulate the cursor shifting. Or, U wanted to get back the "native cursor shifting" feature. I'm sorry if I'm not so clear

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the [_getch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) function from the Microsoft C runtime library:

> The **_getch** and **_getwch** functions read a single character from the
>   console without echoing the character. None of these functions can be
>   used to read CTRL+C. When reading a function key or an arrow key, each
>   function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and
>   the second call returns the actual key code.

So, if `_getch()` returns either 0 or 0xE0 (224), you'll have to call the function *again* to see which specific key was pressed.

At least on my machine, these “extended” character codes are as follows (in decimal):

- 0 59 = F1
- 0 60 = F2
- 0 61 = F3
- 0 62 = F4
- 0 63 = F5
- 0 64 = F6
- 0 65 = F7
- 0 66 = F8
- 0 67 = F9
- 0 68 = F10
- 224 71 = Home
- 224 72 = ↑ (up arrow)
- 224 73 = Page Up
- 224 75 = ← (left arrow)
- 224 77 = → (right arrow)
- 224 79 = End
- 224 80 = ↓ (down arrow)
- 224 81 = Page Down
- 224 82 = Insert
- 224 83 = Delete
- 224 133 = F11
- 224 134 = F12

As for what to *do* with these codes, take a look at [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) and related console API functions.